# R keep only columns with name endings that match string in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I would like to only keep those columns whose name-endings match the endings of string entries in a specific other column.

My current data frame:

```r
df <- structure(list(t1copeact_1_1_1 = structure(c(NA, 3, 4, NA, 4, 
NA, 3, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, NA, 4, NA, NA, 3), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeact_1_1_2 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 3, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeact_1_1_3 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeact_1_1_4 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeact_1_1_5 = structure(c(NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeact_1_1_6 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA, 2, 4, 3), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeact_1_1_7 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 
    NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeact_1_1_8 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 3, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeplan_1_1_1 = structure(c(NA, 4, 4, NA, 4, NA, 3, 4, 
    4, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA, 4), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeplan_1_1_2 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 3, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeplan_1_1_3 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeplan_1_1_4 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeplan_1_1_5 = structure(c(NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 4, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeplan_1_1_6 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 4, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, 4), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeplan_1_1_7 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 
    NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), display_width = 0L), 
    t1copeplan_1_1_8 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 4, 3, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3), display_width = 0L), 
    max_sev = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("T1Severity_1", 
    "T1Severity_5", "T1Severity_6", "T1Severity_8"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 19L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

So what I would like to get is this:

```
output_df <- structure(list(copeact = c(NA, NA, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA), 
    copeplan = c(NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

As you can see, in the *output_df* "copeact" column are the values from the df "t1copeact_1_1_x" column that matches the ending of the string in the df "max_sev" column.

For example, the ending in the first row of the df "max_sev" column is "**5**", so I want to keep the value of the t1copeact_1_1_5 (=NA) and the t1copeplan_1_1_5 (=NA) columns (and nothing else). When the ending of "max_sev" is "_**8**", I want to keep the values of t1copeact_1_1_8 and t1copeplan_1_1_8 and so on.

Can someone give me a hint on how to approach this? I'm really lost a bit here. Please tell me if you need more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -max_sev, names_to = c(".value", "index"), names_pattern = "t1(\\w+)_1_1_(\\d$)") %>%
  filter(str_extract(as.character(max_sev), "\\d$") == index)
```

First you transform your data to `long` format using `pivot_longer`: this has the advantage that the column ending is now in a separate column named `index`.
Then, you simply use `filter`.

```
   max_sev      index copeact copeplan
   <fct>        <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 T1Severity_5 5          NA       NA
 2 T1Severity_5 5          NA       NA
 3 T1Severity_1 1           4        4
 4 T1Severity_8 8           3        4
 5 T1Severity_8 8           4        4
 6 T1Severity_5 5           4        4
 7 T1Severity_1 1           3        3
 8 T1Severity_5 5          NA       NA
 9 T1Severity_5 5          NA       NA
10 T1Severity_5 5          NA       NA
11 T1Severity_8 8           4        3
12 T1Severity_5 5          NA       NA
13 T1Severity_5 5          NA       NA
14 T1Severity_1 1           4        4
15 T1Severity_1 1           4        3
16 T1Severity_5 5          NA       NA
17 T1Severity_1 1           4        4
18 T1Severity_5 5          NA       NA
19 T1Severity_5 5          NA       NA
20 T1Severity_8 8           3        3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one base R option :

```
#Unique group value
cols <- c('copeact', 'copeplan')
#get the number from max_sev
vals <- sub('.*_', '', df$max_sev)

#Create a row/column matrix to subset the data 
#from the relevant column in the group
sapply(cols, function(x) {
  as.numeric(df[cbind(1:nrow(df), 
              match(sprintf('t1%s_1_1_%s',x, vals), names(df)))])
})

#      copeact copeplan
# [1,]      NA       NA
# [2,]      NA       NA
# [3,]       4        4
# [4,]       3        4
# [5,]       4        4
# [6,]       4        4
# [7,]       3        3
# [8,]      NA       NA
# [9,]      NA       NA
#[10,]      NA       NA
#[11,]       4        3
#[12,]      NA       NA
#[13,]      NA       NA
#[14,]       4        4
#[15,]       4        3
#[16,]      NA       NA
#[17,]       4        4
#[18,]      NA       NA
#[19,]      NA       NA
#[20,]       3        3
```